# How to write hdf5 files without overwriting?

Tags: python, h5py

Sorry if this is a very basic question on `h5py`.

I was reading the documentation, but I didn't find a similar example.

I'm trying to create multiple hdf5 datasets with Python, but it turns out after I close the file data will be overwritten.

Let's say I do the following:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
f = h5py.File('test.hdf5', 'w')
f.create_dataset('data1', data = np.ones(10))
f.close()
f = h5py.File('test.hdf5', 'w')
f.create_dataset('data0', data = np.zeros(10))
f.close()
f = h5py.File('test.hdf5', 'r')
f["data1"].value
f.close()
```

I get

> KeyError: "Unable to open object (Object 'data1' doesn't exist)"

If I append data, that requires first opening in `'w'` mode and then appending in `'a'` mode, having two different statements.

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
f = h5py.File('test.hdf5', 'w')
f.create_dataset('data1', data = np.ones(10))
f.close()
f = h5py.File('test.hdf5', 'a')
f.create_dataset('data0', data = np.zeros(10))
f.close()
f = h5py.File('test.hdf5', 'r')
f["data1"].value
f.close()
```

If I open the file in `'a'` mode in both cases:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
f = h5py.File('test.hdf5', 'a')
f.create_dataset('data1', data = np.ones(10))
f.close()
f = h5py.File('test.hdf5', 'a')
f.create_dataset('data0', data = np.zeros(10))
f.close()
f = h5py.File('test.hdf5', 'r')
print(f['data1'].value)
f.close()
```

> RuntimeError: Unable to create link (Name already exists)

According to the documentation, data should be stored contiguously, but I didn't find how to avoid overwriting data.

How can I store data on a previously closed hdf5 only using one single statement?

Comment: Could you try restarting python (or your ide) to make sure all files are closed. I assume your first attempt left the file open because it exited with an exception.

Comment: So you basically do not want to open the file in `'a'` mode ? Or am I understanding you quesiton wrongly?

Comment: @Daniel I'm closing the file after getting the exception. I'm trying to find a way to use the same line to write and append data.

Comment: @AnandSKumar I want to use one single mode to write or append data. That will be called from a loop, and if I use `'a'` mode the file has to be previously opened in `'w'` mode outside the loop.

Comment: No , it doesn't if the file you are trying to open with `'a'` mode does not previously exist, it will create the file . Check the documentation - `a Read/write if exists, create otherwise (default)` . You can just always use `a` mode.

Comment: @AnandSKumar If I use `'a'` mode, it tells me that the name already exists. So I just just delete the dataset, the file or is there any other way?

Comment: If you want to create a unique file in each run, then you should consider naming the file like that, such that in each run you produce a new file (maybe add a timestamp to the name) . If that is not possible, are you trying to delete the file before recreating it for each run of the script?

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that

Comment: Ok cool, I have added an answer for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a unique file in each run, then you should consider naming the file like that , an example would be to add the timestamp to the name of the file, A very simply example would be to use `datetime` module and `now` and `strftime` method to create the file name. Example -

```
import datetime
filename = "test_{}.hdf5".format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S"))
```

Then you can use that filename to open the file.

---

Demo -

```
>>> import datetime
>>> filename = "test_{}.hdf5".format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S"))
>>> filename
'test_2015_08_09_13_33_43.hdf5'
```